# How to get json payload for a C++ json post

Tags: c++, json, http, cgi

I need to create a c++ cgi app the accepts post data.  I will be accepting a json object.  How to I get the payload?

I can get the get data using the below

```
int main() {
    bool DEBUG = true;

    cout << "content-type: text/html" << endl << endl;

    //WHAT GOES HERE FOR POST
    json=?????

    //THIS IS A GET
    query_string = getenv("QUERY_STRING");

}
```

Comment: I am sure it depends on the web server calling your app. But apache delivers it on stdin see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

Comment: @LokiAstari This is common behaviour, see [Wikipedia - CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) and [RFC 3875](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-4.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method type is *POST* (you may also want to check this) then the POST-data is written to stdin. You can therefore use standard methods like this:

```
// Do not skip whitespace, more configuration may also be needed.
cin >> noskipws;

// Copy all data from cin, using iterators.
istream_iterator<char> begin(cin);
istream_iterator<char> end;
string json(begin, end);

// Use the JSON data somehow.
cout << "JSON was " << json << endl;
```

This will read all data from *cin* into *json* until an EOF occurs.

Comment: An easier way not to skip white space is to use the `std::istreambuf_iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming apache:

The [documentation is found here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html):

You will find it near the bottom but the post data is provided over stdin.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{   
    bool DEBUG = true;

    std::cout << "content-type: text/html\n\n"; // prefer \n\n to std::endl
                                                // you probably don't want to flush immediately.

    std::stringstream post;
    post << std::cin.rdbuf();

    std::cout << "Got: " << post.str() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @Tampa: See `Olaf Dietsche` comments above. He says it defined in RFC 3875. So probably. But you should read your documentation (or just try it see what happens).